# I can't seem to align my PrimeNG Calendar component

Tags: css, angular, primeng, ng-deep

```
::ng-deep p-calendar.calendar-control > span > input.p-inputtext {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #eeeeee;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

The text is not being aligned to the center

```
          <p-calendar dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" dateMask autoUnmask="true"
          [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid ng-dirty':f['tdate']?.errors &&f['tdate']?.touched}"
          formControlName="tdate" id="tdate" class="date " placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
          name="tdate" [(ngModel)]="dateModel" 
          [disabled]="isDisabled"              
          ></p-calendar>
```

[image: text is left aligned]

Answer (score 2):

Your .scss file:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .date {
    .p-inputtext {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```

your component:

```
 <p-calendar dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" dateMask autoUnmask="true"
          [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid ng-dirty':f['tdate']?.errors &&f['tdate']?.touched}"
          formControlName="tdate" id="tdate" class="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
          name="tdate" [(ngModel)]="dateModel" 
          [disabled]="isDisabled"              
          ></p-calendar>
```